# PostgreSQL - Include all rows from joined tables

Tags: postgresql, join

So I've been playing with joins and trying to find the best way to accomplish this.

Let's say I have these tables. Not putting all columns for brevity sake. But table A has several more columns than B.

```
              Table A
             ---------
| id | member_id | data | updated
```

Then this table

```
              Table B
             ---------
| id | post_id | member_id | post_date
```

Table `B.post_id` is a foreign key to `Table A.id`

I want to join table A and B but return all rows. Right now I can only get it to return all rows from table A and only matched ones from table b. I need the rows table B matched on as well from Table A and then ORDER BY DESC greatest of the 2 time columns.

Here is the query I've been playing with

```
SELECT a.*, b.member_id as poster, b.post_date, c.title, c.level 
  FROM tableA as a LEFT JOIN tableC as c ON c.a_id=a.a_id 
   LEFT JOIN tableB as b ON a.id=b.post_id 
    WHERE a.member_id IN (100,101) OR b.member_id IN (100,101) 
     ORDER BY GREATEST(a.updated,b.post_date) DESC LIMIT 10
```

I don't get the desired results. If I have a row with ID 20 from table A that join is matched in table b, I only get the row from table b in the results and instead of both rows from both tables. I've played with many ways and tried other answers on SO, just not working out. The query should perform well with many records. If someone has a better and more performance way to do this and make it work please share.

Here is sample data:

Table A

```
id   | member_id | data | updated
--- -------   ---------   ---------
10  |   101      | data | 1495081193
11  |   100      | data | 1495081500
12  |   101      | data | 1495081600
```

Table B

```
id  post_id | member_id | post_date
--- -------   ---------   ---------
2  |   10   | 101      | 1495083000
3  |   10   | 100      | 1495083500
```

So what I'm expecting for results is on the join is

```
id  post_id | member_id  | data | post_date   | updated
--- -------   ---------   ------  ---------     -------
3  |   10   |   100      | data | 1495083500  | 1495081193
2  |   10   |   101      | data | 1495083000  | 1495081193
12 |        |   101      | data |             | 1495081600
11 |        |   100      | data |             | 1495081500
10 |        |   101      | data |             | 1495081193
```

But I'm only getting this without the column that was matched being the last one.

```
id  post_id | member_id  | data | post_date   | updated
--- -------   ---------   ------  ---------     -------
3  |   10   |   100      | data | 1495083500  | 1495081193
2  |   10   |   101      | data | 1495083000  | 1495081193
12 |        |   101      | data |             | 1495081600
11 |        |   100      | data |             | 1495081500
```

That is a *rough* example, note I'm ordering by GREATEST to use the timestamps of either column.

Comment: I don't get it. Please show some sample data for A, for B, the result you get, and the result you expect.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very strange query result. After all it's two queries combined:

- get all A records
- get all B records with joined A data

The query is hence a union query:

```
selectid b.id, b.post_id, b.member_id, a.data, b.post_date, a.updated
from b
join a on a.id = b.post_id
union all
select id a.id, null, a.member_id, a.data, null, a.updated
from a
order by greatest(updated, coalesce(post_date, updated)) desc;
```

Comment: This gave the direction I needed using Union, this and another post helped me come up with the solution. Thanks